# How to wait until element present in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xpath, sleep, tampermonkey

```
(function() {
    document.evaluate('/html/body/nav/section[4]/div/form[1]/input[4]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click();
    Sleep(15);
    window.close();
})();
```

So the click function works but as soon as I add the Sleep windows.close no longer works? Im stil learning Javascript so can someone help please? All I want to do is have it click the Vote Up button then Close the active tab.

Comment: There is no `Sleep` in the javascript, which is why your script is breaking.

Comment: I have tried a setTimeout(function, milliseconds) but then my Script skips over the click part and just closes the tab without executing the click function. I noticed the website URL changes to ImageNumber?flash=Rated%20Image after I click on the Vote Up button. How can I detect the URL Change then have Window.close execute?

Answer (score 1):

Try this function which will wait while the element is present.

```
function waitWhileElementPresent(cssLocator, timeoutInSeconds) {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    var endTime = currentTime + timeoutInSeconds * 1000;
    var checkExist = setInterval(function () {
        if (document.querySelectorAll(cssLocator).length == 0) {
            clearInterval(checkExist);
            console.log('waited until element not present.');
            return;
        } else if (endTime < new Date().getTime()) {
            clearInterval(checkExist);
            console.log('element still found after ' + timeoutInSeconds + ' seconds.');
            return;
        } else { 
            console.log('waiting for element not present ...'); 
        } 
    }, 100);
}
```

Here is the other function that will wait until the element is present

```
function waitUntilElementPresent(cssLocator, timeoutInSeconds) {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    var endTime = currentTime + timeoutInSeconds * 1000;
    var checkExist = setInterval(function () {
        if (document.querySelectorAll(cssLocator).length) {
            clearInterval(checkExist);
            return;
        } else if (endTime < new Date().getTime()) {
            clearInterval(checkExist);
            console.log('not found in specified time.');
            return;
        } else {
            console.log('waiting for element to be present…');
        } 
    }, 100); 
}
```

Comment: document.evaluate('/html/body/nav/section[4]/div/form[1]/input[4]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click(); and Window.Close are the two most important aspects of my script how would I implant them in your code to make the timer close the webpage?

Comment: you have to build the right css for your element, can you please share either the url or html of the form and input.

Answer (score 1):

with [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

i use like this

```
(function() {

    // monitor the page for changes and reapply if necessary
    // use 'observer.disconnect()' in 'fnCheckChanges()' to stop monitoring

    var alvo = document.querySelector('body');
    var observer = new MutationObserver(fnCheckChanges);
    observer.observe(alvo, { attributes: true, characterData: true, childList: true, subtree: true });

})();

function fnCheckChanges(changes, observer) {

    // your code here

    console.log('page changed');

}
```